# ¿Como borrar los espacios al inicio y final en MySql?

Tags: mysql

Buenas tardes Saludos a todos!!!

Por favor su apoyo con esta duda de `MySQL` base de datos northwind:

Debo Listar el nombre de las distintas ciudades de la tabla customers, normal y en reverso. Asegurándose de eliminar los espacios en blanco del inicio y el final de la ciudad. Todo debe aparecer en mayúsculas.

Estoy armando esta sintaxis ***pero no se como eliminar los espacios en blanco al inicio y final de cada palabra. Por ello solicito de su orientación.***

Tengo este query:

```
Select upper(City) ciudad, reverse(upper(City)) reverso 
From customers<
```

Comment: una duda mas por favor como podria, generar un query que muestre un numero entero (sin parte decimal) aleatorio entre 0 y 100 , un literal numérico fijo, la raíz cuadrada de ese número, y el resultado de elevar ese mismo número a la 3.

Answer (score 3):

Para eliminar los espacios que la cadena pueda contener al inicio o al final, puedes usar [`TRIM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

#### Ejemplo:

```
Select UPPER(TRIM(City)) ciudad, REVERSE(UPPER(TRIM(City))) reverso 
From customers
```

Comment: Mil Gracias y Saludos.